# Is there a way to add a notification that is more than 4 weeks in advance of a Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar

It looks like [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/) event notifications can only be scheduled a maximum of 4 weeks in advance.

For example, when I try to add a notification that is 5 weeks in advance of the event, I receive the following warning:

> **Must be between 0 and 4 weeks**

[image: Event Details screenshot: Notification: Must be between 0 and 4 weeks]

Is there a way to add a notification that is more than 4 weeks in advance of the event?

Comment: Google still limits it to 4 weeks.